# how to add x-axis and y-axis value in the bar chart using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

this is my code:

```
ggplot(data = samplesolution2, aes(x = transdt, y = transAmount, group = bankAcctID, fill = bankAcctID)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_test(label = rownames(data), nudge_x = 0.25, nudge_y =  0.25, check_overlap = T) +
  ggtitle(label = "Showing Only Total Deposits Over $200") +
  facet_wrap(~ bankAcctID, ncol = 1) 

Error in geom_test(label = rownames(data), nudge_x = 0.25, nudge_y = 0.25,  : 
  could not find function "geom_test"
```

And I want to add x and y value inside each bar.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you make the code example reproducible by providing a sample of the data?

Comment: Hi Katherine, welcome to Stack Overflow. If my answer below doesn't fix your problem, please provide at least a sample of your data with `dput(samplesolution2)` or if your data is very large `dput(samplesolution2[1:10,])`. You can edit your question and paste the output. You can surround it with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more info.

Comment: > dput(samplesolution2[1:4, ])
structure(list(bankAcctID = c("775044", "775044", "775044", "775044"
), startdt = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2018-05-01", class = "factor"), 
    amt = c(858.46, 858.46, 858.46, 858.46), transdt = structure(c(18334, 
    18348, 18362, 18376), class = "Date"), transAmount = c(373.73, 
    360.22, 351.21, 360.22), TtransAmount = c(-443.23, -274.03, 
    -507.25, -498.24), EOD = c(415.23, 584.43, 351.21, 360.22
    )), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two problems:

1. Typo in `geom_text`
2. You need to use the name of your data.frame in your call to `rownames` instead of "data".

```
ggplot(data = samplesolution2, 
       aes(x = transdt, y = transAmount, group = bankAcctID, fill = bankAcctID)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(label = rownames(samplesolution2), nudge_x = 0.25, nudge_y = 0.25, check_overlap = T) +
  ggtitle(label = "Showing Only Total Deposits Over $200") +
  facet_wrap(~ bankAcctID, ncol = 1)
```

Comment: I actually changed code to:  geom_text(aes(x = transdt, y = transAmount, label = transdt)), but this can only show the transdt on the bar. How to show both transAmount and transdt?